# Ordering by multiple fields

Tags: django

I'm wanting to order a queryset based on a couple of different related fields

Models.py

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

class Job(models.Model):
   event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   appointment = models.ForeignKey(appointment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

views.py

```
qs = Job.objects.all().order_by('event__start_time','appointment__start_time')
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Will this always order all of the jobs in the correct order based on the associated star time?

Thanks!

Comment: you can always check the raw sql query that will be generated for this queryset by `str(qs.query)` and check if the fields are listed in the correct/wanted order.

Comment: sorry, I don't know much sql

Comment: and also you should be using [**`select_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for this.